# Bluetooth Serial Ionic don't work on Android device but working on IOS

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm very sad because I have try a lot of things to make my app running good on android.
I'm using Ionic with Vue.js. The code is running well on IOS but it's returning ('Unable to connect to this device on Android')

```
      this.bluetoothSerial.connect("XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:99").subscribe(
        () => {
          // this.test++
          this.bluetoothSerial.subscribeRawData().subscribe(
            data => this.dataWatt = decoder.decode(data),
            error => alert(error + '2')
          )
        },
        (error) => {
          alert(error)
        }
      )
```

I don't use bluetoothSerial to scan all devices but BLE. I don't know what doing...

Comment: did you find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-bluetooth-serial#connect

According to the bluetoothSerial documentation:

**connect**

> Connect to a Bluetooth device.
> bluetoothSerial.connect(macAddress_or_uuid, connectSuccess,connectFailure);

**Description**

> Function connect connects to a Bluetooth device. The callback is long running. Success will be called when the connection is successful. Failure is called if the connection fails, or later if the connection disconnects. An error message is passed to the failure callback.

**Android**

> For Android, connect takes a MAC address of the remote device.

**iOS**

> For iOS, connect takes the UUID of the remote device. Optionally, you can pass an empty string and the plugin will connect to the first BLE peripheral.

**Windows Phone**

> For Windows Phone, connect takes a MAC address of the remote device. The MAC address can optionally surrounded with parenthesis. e.g. (AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF)

**Parameters**

> macAddress_or_uuid: Identifier of the remote device.
>
> connectSuccess: Success callback function that is invoked when the connection is successful.
>
> connectFailure: Error callback function, invoked when error occurs or the connection disconnects.

And here is a preview from the documentation in addition to the reference for the documentation.

Maybe its connecting to iOS even if the mac is wrong...
Check if you are entering the remote address or uuid for Android correctly.